# Call loop html jinja does not work to call some images on table HTML

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'd like to call some image to show on `table.html` from the `controller/static/foto` folder

When I call value foto with python function `img_dir` on HTML using `for loop`

**info/views.py**

```py
import controller import create app
import os

@info_blue.route('/img_dir')
def img_dir():
   app = create_app('dev')
   images = os.listdir('controller/static/foto')
   return render_template("table.html", foto=images)
```

**table.html**

```html
{% for row in value %}
<tr>
   <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
   <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
   <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
   <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
   <td>
      {% for image in foto %}
         <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='controller/static/foto/' + image) }}">
      {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

It doesn't seem to work, but when I try to check the contents of the folder with `print(images)`, I check there are 3 photos

3 photos inside folder from folder path `controller/static/foto`
[image: 1]

Why is it still empty?

Table on column foto seems not showing any photo's
[image: 2]

*Note*: in the foto column, it only contains a varchar of the photo's name from database, just to indicate whether its the right photo when the photo showed up

This is the folder path
[image: This is the folder path]

Tried to call single image from `foto/`

```html
{% for row in value %}
<tr>
   <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
   <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
   <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
   <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
   <td>
      {% for image in foto %}
         <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='controller/static/foto/' + image) }}">
      {% endfor %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='foto/18_Aug_2021|02:33.jpg' + image) }}">
    </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

It works but only outside image loop

Call single image inside row loop, but outside image loop
[image: 4]

when i tried inspect the URL this is the result, its like the image not called ?

[inspect the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvnY0.png)

```
{% for image in foto %} 
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='foto/'+image) }}"> 
{% endfor %} 
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='foto/18_Aug_2021|02:33.jpg' ) }}">
```

when i do this even the '+image' do it without space

[second image inspect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQFcW.png)

copy directly to your comment and got jinja2.exception
[got Jinja2.exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvNjH.png)

[directly copy source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWr2c.png)

test with path variable, no error but not working

[you implement it like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2axr.png)

[if its work, there should be two picture each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cBbL.png)

new inspect for path variable

[just delete {{ row 4 }} those space must be from unimplement code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sn0r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is because there's a function called table which return table.html like this, that's why the return function from img_dir didnt work

[the system taking priority of return function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0oBZ.png)

the solution is id merge them as one, so the return will do it together as one, no one taking the priority.

[merge the code as one return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quH5o.png)

the result they called, but another issue has occured, might take the new ticket i guess

[problem solved but its just beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXHJ9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file path you are sending is correct or not.
I think you have put static path twice in file path.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='controller/static/foto/' + image) }}">
```

Here in filename parameter 'controller/static/' should not be there, remove it and try.

I think it will work.